hacky backprop outperforms clean backprop - Why?
I implemented a basic NN for MNIST in Numpy and started with a hacky implementation of backprop (just randomly multiplying gradients together), but somehow that one works better than my cleaned up version (consitently about 10% more accuracy)
Here is my code, tried to figure it out for 3 days and don't understand the difference. Would highly appreciate if someone could explain it to me:
class NeuralNetwork:
def __init__(self, input_size, l1_size, l2_size, output_size, init=(-.5,.5), learning_rate= 0.02, dtype = np.float64):
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.l1_size = l1_size
    self.l2_size = l2_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.W1 = np.random.uniform(low=init[0], high=init[1], size=(self.input_size, self.l1_size)).astype(dtype)
    self.W2 = np.random.uniform(low=init[0], high=init[1], size=(self.l1_size, self.l2_size)).astype(dtype)
    self.W3 = np.random.uniform(low=init[0], high=init[1], size=(self.l2_size, self.output_size)).astype(dtype) 
    self.alpha = learning_rate
    

def forward(self, x_):
    # Layer 1
    self.x_ = x_
    self.l1_ = self.x_ @ self.W1
    self.a1_ = sigmoid(self.l1_)
    # Layer 2
    self.l2_ = self.a1_ @ self.W2
    self.a2_ = sigmoid(self.l2_)
    # Layer 3
    self.o_ = self.a2_ @ self.W3
    self.s_ = softmax(self.o_)

    return self.s_

def backward_clean(self, y_, output_):
    mem = output_ - y_
    # (5,1) x (1,3) = (5,3)
    self.dW3 = self.a2_.reshape(self.l2_size, 1) @ mem
    mem = self.W3 @ mem.T * d_sigmoid(self.l2_).reshape(self.l2_size, 1)
    # (5,1) x (1,5) = (5,5)
    self.dW2 = self.a1_.reshape(self.l1_size, 1) @ mem.T
    mem = self.W2 @ mem * d_sigmoid(self.l1_).reshape(self.l1_size, 1)
    # (4,1) x (1,5) x (5,5) * (1,5) = (4,5)
    self.dW1 = self.x_.reshape(self.input_size, 1) @ mem.T
    self.W3 = self.W3 - self.alpha * self.dW3
    self.W2 = self.W2 - self.alpha * self.dW2 
    self.W1 = self.W1 - self.alpha * self.dW1

def backward_hacky(self, y_, output_):
    tmp = output_ - y_
    self.dW3 = self.a2_.reshape(self.l2_size, 1) @ tmp
    tmp2 = d_sigmoid(self.l2_).reshape(self.l2_size, 1) @ (tmp @ self.W3.T)
    self.dW2 = tmp2 * self.a1_.reshape(self.l1_size, 1)
    self.dW1 = (self.x_.reshape(self.input_size, 1) @ d_sigmoid(self.l1_).reshape(self.l1_size, 1).transpose()) @ (tmp2 @ self.W2.T)

    self.W3 = self.W3 - self.alpha * self.dW3
    self.W2 = self.W2 - self.alpha * self.dW2 
    self.W1 = self.W1 - self.alpha * self.dW1

def train(self, X, Y):
    self.outputs = []
    self.losses = []
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        output = self.forward(X[i]).reshape((1, self.output_size))
        if len(self.outputs) == 0:
            self.outputs = output
        else:
            np.append(self.outputs, output, axis=0)
        actual = Y[i].reshape((1, self.output_size))
        self.losses.append(se(output, actual))
        self.backward(actual, output)
    return self.losses


I'm not sure I'm following your code, but it looks like you calculated the derivative of squared error incorrectly. It should be -2(actual - output). Maybe try this and see what happens.

That did not change much, also it is in both backwards functions the same. The main problem is that i do not understand why "backwards_hacky" function reduces loss more efficient than the correct implementation in "backwards_clean"

Maybe try returning a list of all the gradients you calculated and see how different they are. It's worth noting that often times what makes sense "mathematically" doesn't always work out in practice (ex. ReLU being more popular than sigmoid). It could also just be a problem with your training loop - look closely at how both implementations train. Also, you say 10% more accurate, but it's not clear what that really means without looking more closely. Look at how the accuracy breaks down between classes and see if there are differences.

In fact the the gradients that arrive in the first layer are (absolute) larger with the hacky implementation. That does explain why it optimizes faster, but I still do not understand why the gradients are different, the formulas are the same. Or they look the same to me.
